# Check foreign key constraint violation

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys

In SQLite foreign keys disabled by default, so we can accidentally insert row in the table that violate foreign key constraint.
After this we can enable foreign keys via
`PRAGMA foreign_keys=on`
 and want to check that all
rows in our table satisfies corresponding constraints. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign_key_check pragma will show you constraint violations.

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_check

Comment: Great! This is exactly what i need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend utilising Foreign Keys you should enable Foreign keys when making the connection.

However, the following demonstrates one way you could ascertain invalid references using `NOT IN` :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_reference INTEGER -- WOULD/COULD have REFERENCES usertable (id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- REFERENCED column
    user_name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES
    (null,'Fred'),
    (null,'Bert'),
    (null,'Tom')
;
INSERT INTO main_table VALUES
    (null,1), -- References FRED (most likely)
    (null,'not a valid reference'), -- oooops this will not reference a user
    (null,2)
;
SELECT * FROM main_table 
    WHERE user_reference 
    NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM user_table
        )
;
```

The result being :-

[image]

If you simply wanted an indication then the following would return 0 if there were no invalid references or the number of invalid references (e.g. 1 when applied to the above):-

```
SELECT count() FROM main_table
    WHERE user_reference
    NOT IN (
            SELECT id FROM user_table
        )
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested alternative way, but i want to utilize foreign keys.